# Making images more responsive relative to a non background image. Resize and stuck in a fixed position

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, bootstrap-4

I need help making my icons around the main wheel be more responsive to the page size increasing and decreasing. Right now they move around and I need them to stay put relevant to the middle wheel. I also would like the wheel and icons to resize better when the page shrinks or grows. I feel like it has something to do with my positioning but I am not sure. Been stuck for hours. Anything helps!

My website is www.marshalllanning.com and I will put my CSS code below...

```
.bg {
/* Set rules to fill background */
min-height: 100%;
min-width: 1024px;

/* Set up proportionate scaling */
width: 100%;
height: auto;

/* Set up positioning */
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;

z-index: 0;
}

.navbar-custom {
background-color: black;
z-index: 3;
}

.navbar-brand
{
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
left: 0;
text-align: center;
margin: 0;
}
.navbar-toggle {
z-index:3;
}

.navbar-custom .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
background-color: red;
}

.navbar-custom .navbar-toggle {
background-color: white;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) { /* Specific to 
this particular image */
.bg {
left: 50%;
margin-left: -512px;   /* 50% */
}
}

.img1 {
border-radius: 50%;
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
width: 500px;
height: 500px;
border-color: white;
border-width: 15px;
border-style: solid;
position: absolute;
margin: 0;
top: 52%;
left: 50%;
margin-right: -50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
z-index: 1;
}

.fb {
border-radius: 20%;
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
width: 64px;
height: 64px;
position: absolute;
margin: 0;
top: 30%;
left: 34%;
margin-right: -50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
z-index: 2;
border-color: black;
border-width: 1px;
border-style: solid;
}

.fb:hover {
opacity: 0.7;
}

.sc {
border-radius: 20%;
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
position: absolute;
margin: 0;
top: 16.8%;
left: 50%;
margin-right: -50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
z-index: 2;
border-color: black;
border-width: 1px;
border-style: solid;
}

.sc:hover {
opacity: 0.7;
}

.gh {
border-radius: 20%;
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
width: 64px;
height: 64px;
position: absolute;
margin: 0;
top: 30%;
left: 66%;
margin-right: -50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
z-index: 2;
background-color: white;
border-color: black;
border-width: 1px;
border-style: solid;
}

.gh:hover {
opacity: 0.7;
}

.ig {
border-radius: 20%;
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
width: 64px;
height: 64px;
position: absolute;
margin: 0;
top: 83%;
left: 50%;
margin-right: -50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
z-index: 2;
border-color: black;
border-width: 1px;
border-style: solid;
}

.ig:hover {
opacity: 0.7;
}

.li {
border-radius: 20%;
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
width: 64px;
height: 64px;
position: absolute;
margin: 0;
top: 50%;
left: 30%;
margin-right: -50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
z-index: 2;
border-color: black;
border-width: 1px;
border-style: solid;
}

.li:hover {
opacity: 0.7;
}

.xb {
border-radius: 20%;
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
width: 64px;
height: 64px;
position: absolute;
margin: 0;
top: 50%;
left: 70%;
margin-right: -50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
z-index: 2;
border-color: black;
border-width: 1px;
border-style: solid;
}

.xb:hover {
opacity: 0.7;
}

.az {
border-radius: 20%;
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
width: 64px;
height: 64px;
position: absolute;
margin: 0;
top: 70%;
left: 66%;
margin-right: -50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
z-index: 2;
border-color: black;
border-width: 1px;
border-style: solid;
}

.az:hover {
opacity: 0.7;
}

.gc {
border-radius: 20%;
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
width: 64px;
height: 64px;
position: absolute;
margin: 0;
top: 70%;
left: 34%;
margin-right: -50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
z-index: 2;
border-color: black;
border-width: 1px;
border-style: solid;
}

.gc:hover {
opacity: 0.7;
}

.center {
color: whitesmoke;
height: 10em;
position: absolute;
margin: 0;
top: 30%;
left: 50%;
margin-right: -50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a div around all items like `<div style="width: 500px;height: 500px;position: relative;margin: auto;">` and then change in css the top and the left values.